# how to show ckeditor plugin button as clicked button

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I have a created a custom ckeditor plugin using this [tutorial](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/?mobile=/guide/plugin_sdk_sample) and this is working fine. I just want to show plugin button as selected/enabled/clicked when I click it the first time like **Bold** plugin button behaves. I have checked it applies 
`cke_button cke_button_on` classes when I click on the bold button. But I haved googled but did not get the way to do the same.

How can I achieve the same? Please ignore if you feel it is too basic to ask, but I have tried a lot but did not get any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to change the state of the command. So

```
var commandState = editor.getCommand("COMMAND_NAME").state;
if(commandState == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF) {
    commandState = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON;
} else {
    commandState = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
}
editor.getCommand("COMMAND_NAME").setState(commandState);
```

And thats all.